# Question about fields and quotients of polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory

I don't see how to solve the following problem:

> Let $R$ be a commutative and unitary ring. If there exists a monic polynomial $f(x) \in R[x]$ so that $R[x]/(f(x))$ is a field, show that $R$ is a field. What about if $f(x)$ isn't monic?

I don't have a clue about how proving it. I see that if $R$ is a field and $f(x)$ a monic and irreducible polynomial in $R[X]$ then $\frac{R[x]}{(f(x))}$ is a field, but that is not the question!

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You *can't* see what you say you see in the second to last paragraph,  because that is not true. Consider ant ring R which is not a field and the polynomial f(x)=x-1.

Comment: of course you're right, I wrote ring but I was thinking on a field. Sorry!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Let $R$ be a commutative unitary ring. If there exists a monic polynomial $f\in R[X]$ so that $R[X]/(f)$ is a field, then $R$ is a field.

Let's first remark that the degree of non-zero polynomials in the ideal $(f)$ is at least $\deg f$. Now let $a\in R$, $a\ne 0$. We want to prove that $a$ is invertible in $R$. The residue class of $a$ in $R[X]/(f)$, denoted in what follows by $\hat a$, is not zero: if $\hat a=\hat 0$, then $a\in(f)$ and since $0=\deg a<\deg f$ we get a contradiction. Since  $R[X]/(f)$ is a field it follows that $\hat a$ is invertible in $R[X]/(f)$, so there is $g\in R[X]$ such that $\hat a\hat g=\hat 1$, that is, $ag-1\in(f)$. Now write $g=fq+r$ with $\deg r<\deg f$. Then $ag-1=a(fq+r)-1=afq+ar-1\in (f)$, so $ar-1\in (f)$. But $\deg ar\le\deg r<\deg f$, and therefore we get $ar=1$. In particular, $ar_0=1$ for some $r_0\in R$. (Of course, $r_0$ is $r(0)$.)

> What about if $f$ isn't monic?

Then the result is false: take $R=\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$, and $f=2X-1$. We have $R[X]/(f)\simeq S^{-1}(\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z)$, where $S=\{1, 2, 4\}$, and $S^{-1}(\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z)\simeq \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ which is a field.

Comment: Thank you very much @user26857: you've given a very clear, short and elegant proof

Comment: This undoubtedly is a very nice answer. +1

Comment: This seems strange to me.. $R[X]/(f)$ is a field iff $(f)$ is a maximal ideal in $R[X]$ - so this result then means that $R[X]$ can only have non-trivial maximal ideals when $R$ is a field?

Comment: No @FireGarden. What this says is that a *principal* ideal in $\;R[x]\;$  can be maximal only if $\;R\;$ is a field.

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

In any case, we can write the elements of $\;R[x]/I\;,\;\;I:=\langle f(x)\rangle\;$ ,  as $\;g(x)+I\;,\;\;\deg g<\deg f\;$ , so assuming $\;\deg f\ge 1\;$ ,we have that the elements $\;r+I\in R[x]/I\;,\;\;0\neq r\in R\;$ are part of a field and since $\;r+I\neq \overline 0=I\;$ , then they all have multiplicative inverse  ...

**Added on the OP's request:** The above hints us to look for a possible embedding $\;R\to R[x]/I\;,\;\;r\mapsto r+I$ (for this I need the assumption that $\;R\;$ is an ID):

$$\forall\,r,s\in R\;,\;\;r+I=s+I\iff r-s\in I\;$$

yet every element in $\;I\;$ is either zero of degree $\;\ge\deg f\;$ (here the assumption kicks in), and thus $\;r-s=0\iff r=s\;$ and we get our embedding.

Now,

$$0\neq r+I\in R/I\implies \exists\,s\in R\;\;s.t.\;\;(rs)+I=1+I\iff rs-1\in I$$

and again, as above, $\;rs=1\;$ and every non-zero element in $\;R\;$ has a multiplicative inverse.

Now, *without the assumption* of ID: as hinted in one of my comments below, we have that from $\;R\;$ is not a field it follows that $\;I\;$ cannot be a maximal ideal and thus the quotient ring isn't a field.

I'm not sure how, and if possible at all, to get rid of the above assumption of ID to make that approach work. If we get lucky, it could possibly be that the user that commented below and chose not to write down an answer/hint/input but rather just to question this answer will now grant us the honour to write down an answer/comment enlightening us all.

Comment: Thank you. And why the polynomial necesarily has to be monic?

Comment: Well, I'm not completely sure, but it may be enough to require the upper coefficient to be a unit in the ring...or perhaps not even that. Haven't thought of that enough...Maybe later I can come up with something.

Comment: I might be missing something, but doesn't this only show that the elements $r \in R \setminus I$ have multiplicative inverse?

Comment: @DanZimm, in fact $\;I\le R[x]\;$ , so $\;R\setminus I=R\setminus \{0\}\;$, when we already identity $\;R\;$ with a subring of $\;R[x]\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio ignore the last comment apparently I forgot how to do algebra for a brief moment

Comment: Hehe....@DanZimm, Welcome to the "Damn, what the heck what I was thinking about!" club in stackexchange.math . I'm the founder and honorary president for life...

Comment: It is not clear what you claim to be proving (or even hinting). What is written is very far from a proof.

Comment: @Bill, you may have missed the first word: "hints"...and, as noted in the above comments, I'm not sure of another related questions asked by the OP. You're invited to write down your input.

Comment: A hint is not useful if it leads nowhere. If you do not know how to prove it then why do you think the hint is useful?

Comment: Again, @BillDubuque: read the last words in my last comment.

Comment: Do you know how to turn this "hint" into a complete proof, yes or no?

Comment: Of course, @B: R is not a field ==> <f(x)> cannot be a maximal ideal (why?). Now, will you write down your input or will you continue to question me?

Comment: @Don How does that relate to what you wrote in your answer? It appears to be a different approach. I'd like to know how you plan to continue from the hint in the answer. If it is not clear to me, how do you expect it to be clear to a student?

Comment: The approach given in my hint was meant to be as elementary as I could: without "in a commutative (unitary) ring a quotient ring is a field iff the ideal is maximal, no prime and maximal ideals in polynomial rings over non-fields, etc. I wrote the hint, some people found it useful, perhaps with this or with that approach. Do you have something different? Knock yourself out and write something. Don't bother in answering this: I've decided to stop this pointless discussion.

Comment: @Don My opinion is that if one gives a hint, and someone doubts that the hint leads anywhere, then one is obliged to give further details when questioned. I am genuinely curious to learn how you plan to complete the answer(hint) to a proof. I suspect that you may have overlooked something. But since you won't say any more, I cannot possibly know. As such, I have downvoted the answer. I will be very glad to retract the downvote if you can show how to proceed from that hint (or give another approach that does not leave any such doubts).

Comment: Thank you all! I appreciate every comment. @DonAntonio could you provide me further details of the proof, please? I've been thinking on this problem and trying to use your hint since you write me but I'm still stuck with this problem: I can't see $R$ is a field and I haven't found a counterexample (in case it exists...) in the assumption that the polynomial is not monic. Thank you very much!

Comment: I can't see where you need the “integral domain” assumption. Division (with remainder) by a monic polynomial is possible for polynomials over any commutative ring, with uniqueness of remainder. You don't need that $r\mapsto r+I$ is an embedding either.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing some idea, but in the way @DonAntonio sees that $R$ is a field without the ID assumption, does it have any importance that $f(x)$ is monic or not?

Comment: @egreg, I see it this way: if $\;R\;$ isn't an ID, we could possibly have $\;rs=0\;,\;\;r,s\neq 0\;$...Of course, **if** this means $\;r+I\,,\,s+I\neq I\;$ we're fine, yet I'm not sure whether we can have $\;r+I=I\;$ *even* when $\;\deg r<\deg f\;$ . It isn't a matter of dividing with residue but of *knowing* that $\;\deg f=k\implies \deg g\ge k\;$ for all$\;0\neq g\in \langle f\rangle\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio For $g\in R[x]$, you can write $g=fq+r$, where $\operatorname{deg}r<\operatorname{deg}f$, because $f$ is monic by assumption. If $g=fq+r=fq_1+r_1$, then $r-r_1=(q_1-q)f$, but the degree of $(q_1-q)f$ is at least equal to the degree of $f$, unless $q=q_1$, because $f$ is monic. Since the degree of $r-r_1$ is surely less than the degree of $f$, we conclude $q=q_1$ and $r=r_1$.

Comment: @egreg, "the degree of $\;(q_1-q)f\;$ is at least..." . How can we be sure of this if we do **not** have an ID? For example, say over $\;R=\Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z\;$ ,we have that $$f(x)=2x^3+3\;,\;\;q(x)=6x\implies q(x)f(x)=6x\;,\;\;\text{yet}\;\;\deg f=3\;,\;\;\deg q=1\ldots$$

Comment: Hmmm, wait: perhaps here the monic condition kicks in...?

Comment: @DonAntonio $f$, in the OP's setting, *is monic*! Lemma: if $f$ is monic and $g\ne0$, then $\operatorname{deg}(fg)=\operatorname{deg}f+\operatorname{deg}g$.

Comment: Yes @egreg, so I saw 10 seconds before your last comment...:)

Comment: thank you very much all of you, specially @DonAntonio. In part, because of your multiple comments and help finally I've understood the solution of the problem I've been stucking with for a few days!

Answer (score 2):

Let me try and clear up the confusion in the comments under DonAntonio's answer, and perhaps why the monic assumption is crucial.

Since $f$ is monic, $(f) \cap R = 0$. Thus the composition $R \to R[x] \to R[x]/(f)$ has kernel $(f) \cap R = 0$, i.e. is injective, so $R \hookrightarrow R[x]/(f)$ is a subring of a field, hence is a domain. Next, $f$ being monic says exactly that $R \hookrightarrow R[x]/(f)$ is an integral extension. Then $R$ is a domain with $\dim R = \dim R[x]/(f) = 0$, hence is a field.

As for an example where this fails if $f$ is not monic, consider $R = \mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$, $f = 2x - 1$. Then $R$ is not a field, but $R[x]/(f) = \mathbb{Z}_{(2)}[x]/(2x-1) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{(2)}[\frac{1}{2}] \cong \mathbb{Q}$ *is* a field (notice that this example is in much the same spirit as the one given by user26857: both are localizations at principal open sets which are fields).